# Want to add new search field in Solr Search

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud, solrnet

We are using Solr 5.2.1 with Zookeeper 3.4.6.

We would like to add an extra search field in the solr search schema, for that we have added filed in schema.xml however it is not reflecting to the solr index.

We have also tried below things -
1. Started Zookeeper as well as solr services.
2. Tried to reload the core

Could you please share what we need to do fix this issue?

Thank You in advance.

Bhagwat Mane

Comment: can you post schema field and its definition that you added. How you are telling that new field is not reflecting. Did you tried indexing docs with that new field ? Did you check in Solr admin Analysis page. ?

Comment: Do you get any error messages when indexing documents with the field? You won't see a new field unless you've actually indexed content for the field - the field won't show up empty in all existing documents just by being added to the schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You Pihentagyu,

Short steps for above discussion -

Considering :

- You are running solr in cloud mode with Zookeeper
- You are using schemaFactory as ManagedIndexSchemaFactory in the solrconfig.xml file

Follow below steps to reflect changes made in schema.xml to zookeeper configuration -

### For Windows

1. Execute - *zkcli.bat -cmd upconfig -confdir "C:\path to solr directory\solr\configsets\asi_configs\conf" -confname PRODSEARCH -z 10.0.0.223:2181*
2. Then you need to clear managed-schema to reflect changes from schema.xml to managed-schema. To clear managed-schema execute - 
   *zkcli.bat -cmd clear -z 10.0.0.223:2181 /configs/PRODSEARCH/managed-schema*
3. Last step to restart Solr and Zookeeper services.

Where

- zkcli.bat - is present in "solr\server\scripts\cloud-scripts"
- PRODSEARCH - is name of config, you can get it from Solr Admin UI
  under Cloud\Tree\configs\confname

Note : use zkcli.sh for linux.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Solr cloud, you need to update the zookeeper with the new schema. This is done on the solr server in the server/scripts/cloud-scripts directory using the zkcli.sh script, as follows:

```
./zkcli.sh -cmd upconfig -confdir /opt/solr/server/solr/collection0/conf -confname configName -z zookeeper1:2181,zookeeper2:2181,zookeeper3:2181
```

where configName is the name of the config (you can find this in the solr admin panel under cloud-->/configs), zookeeperX is the ip address of zookeeperX, and 2181 is the port number of the zookeeper.

Then, of course, you will need to index, adding data to that field as mentioned above.

Comment: Thank You pihentagyu, we tired to run above commend but not able to see new filed in the *schema browser* section, command - *zkcli.cmd -cmd upconfig -confdir "D:\SolrSetup\SolrSEARCH\solr-5.2.1\server\solr\configsets\asi_configs\conf" -confname STAGESEARCH -z 10.0.0.92:2181*, We are using solr in windows server, we are getting below message after execution of above command -

Comment: Connecting to localhost:2181
2017-01-04 17:41:15,034 [myid:] - INFO [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.6-1569965, built on 02/20/2014 09:09 GMT
2017-01-04 17:41:15,049 [myid:] - INFO [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:host.name=abc.domainname.com
2017-01-04 17:41:15,049 [myid:] - INFO [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:java.version=1.8.0_73
2017-01-04 17:41:15,049 [myid:] - INFO [main:Environment@100] - Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation......

Comment: Did you reload the core on each server after running zkcli?

Comment: yes we did that as well, still same issue. We found out rest API on solr site to add new field in the schema - *https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schema+API*, but we don't know how to use it in windows server   *- curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
  "add-field":{
     "name":"sell-by",
     "type":"tdate",
     "stored":true }
}' http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/schema*

Comment: I'm wondering why your log info is saying 'Connecting to localhost:2181` and not 10.0.0.92:2181. Also, on our system the Windows command is zkcli.bat, not zkcli.cmd. There is a zkCli.cmd on the zookeeper, which can be confusing.

Comment: Thank you Pihentagyu, We are able to see the newly added field under *Files/Schema.xml* file however we are not able to see same under *Schema Browser* (in the dropdown box). We also added new document with this new field but still not able to see field in the search results.

Comment: Hi Pihentagyu, Could you please help me to resole this issue?

Comment: It sounds like you have the config name linked with the collection, since the changes are reflected in the Files. Maybe you could try turning logging on to debug and checking the logs (both in the console and in the log files) whilst reloading the core(s). You also might try restarting solr, rather than just reloading the core.

Comment: As we are using managed-schema, it is working after changing managedSchemaResourceName to managed-schema-1.7 in solrconfig.xml file(inside configs set) however if we want to use managed-schema and want new field changes in this file itself. what should we need to do to reflect schema.xml changes to managed-schema in zookeeper configuration file? we also tried to reload core and restart nodes and zk but still changes are not coming in managed-schema.

Comment: Hi Pihentagyu, Could you please provide your inputs to above comments?

Comment: Hi Pihentagyu, Issues related to managed-schema get resolved after executing *zkcli.bat -cmd clear -z 10.0.0.223:2181 /configs/PRODASISEARCH/managed-schema* command to remove managed-schema and restart solr and zk server.